# Read XML file in android

Tags: android

I have an xml-file that contains data that I want to read. The code works in a desktop environment but I can't figure out how to store and read the file from an android device. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the xml file in the assets folder and fetch it using the AssetManager:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

To read the file use the same java code that works for you on J2SE.