# Android plist xml parsing issue

Tags: android, xml, parsing, plist

I have to parse a plist file in Android application. Plist is similar to xml given on following url:

http://pastie.org/2583229

Will I be able to parse to display data in the app? Which parser is good for this purpose?
Please help me here by giving me some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below I have mentioned one way of parsing that XML. I have used [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) to parse the above mentioned xml:

```
     String str1 ="<Xml to be parsed>";
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            xpp.setInput( new StringReader (str1));
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String str;
             if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                System.out.println("Start document");
             } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                 str    =   xpp.getName();
                 System.out.println("Start tag "+str);

             } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                 System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
             } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                 System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
             }
             eventType = xpp.next();
            }
           System.out.println("End document");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response is xml file so you can read that file using any xml parser

For more details about different types of xml parser follow below link

[Different types of xml parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519254/read-xml-file-in-android/7519410#7519410)