# string parsing to get an attribute java android

Tags: java, android, xml, regex, ksoap2

I am programming in android and I am getting some xml data through SOAP which I am placing in a string object. Now I want to get all the id's from  and put them in an array. How do I do that ??????
From the code below, i want to get the values 1101, 1103 in an array..... please help

```
<getAvailableSpotResult>
         <garage id=1 name='South Garage' address='100 acme dr' city='san jose' state='ca' zip='95052'>
            <floor number='1'>
               <spot id='1101' status='available'/>
               <spot id='1103' status='available'/>
            </floor>
         </garage>
      </getAvailableSpotResult>
```

Comment: Try parsing first or show what you have done for that.

Comment: @Sa Kan Were you able to solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the xml to get the required data. If you google, "How to parse xml in java android", you'll get lots of results. 
First try and read the official documentation on [Parsing XML Data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) and see the examples.

You can check out other similar questions [How to read XML file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464087/how-to-read-xml-file-in-android) and [Read XML file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519254/read-xml-file-in-android). You can also try [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/) tutorial.

Please try to atleast google or see previous answers before asking a question. If there is any specific problem you are facing, everyone would be happy to help.

Comment: +1 for: "Please try to at least google or see previous answers before asking a question"